# Mysql conditional query to list a column from one of the tables but not both

Tags: mysql

We have two tables

table: `publisher` (`publisher_id` is unique)

```
+--------------+------+--+
| publisher_id | name |  |
+--------------+------+--+
|          100 | abc  |  |
|          131 | def  |  |
|          355 | ghi  |  |
+--------------+------+--+
```

table: `publisher_alias` (composite index of `publisher_id` and `name` is unique)

```
+--------------+-------+--+
| publisher_id | name  |  |
+--------------+-------+--+
|          131 | xyz   |  |
|          131 | pqr   |  |
|          355 | mln   |  |
|          355 | opr   |  |
+--------------+-------+--+
```

I am looking for a mysql command that will generate a list of names from the `publisher` table (if alias entry is not found). If the alias entry is found for a given publisher_id, then I want all the `name` from `publisher_alias` to be included in the list (`name` from `publisher` should be omitted). The output should look like this

```
+--+------+--+
|  | name |  |
+--+------+--+
|  | abc  |  |
|  | xyz  |  |
|  | pqr  |  |
|  | mln  |  |
|  | opr  |  |
+--+------+--+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a case when clause

```
select case  when b.name is null then a.name else b.name end
from publisher as a
left join publisher_alias as b  on a.publisher_id  = b.publisher_id
```

Comment: There is a small typo in the command ('the' should be replaced by 'then') but otherwise it is perfect. Thanks

Comment: You can also use the shorter `IFNULL(b.name, a.name)` or the standard `COALESCE(b.name, a.name)`

Comment: @Barmar   . correct .. in this case all the way propose are useful